# Translation question for a Seneca epistle

Tags: classical-latin, sentence-translation, seneca-iunior

I recently came across the aphorism *Nam illa tumultū gaudēns nōn est industria*, from Seneca's epistle "On True and False Friendship". As far as I can tell, a literal translation would be "For rejoicing in tumult is not industry"; the standard idiomatic translation is "For a love of bustle is not industry." But I'm confused about what *illa* is doing in the sentence. Does anyone know why it's there? I can't figure out what it refers to, nor why it's feminine.

Answer (score 6):

I would translate it thus:

> For **that** which rejoices in tumult is not industry.

What may be confusing is the feminine gender of *illa*: in English (and some other Germanic languages), we'd use a neuter pronoun (*that*) in constructions such as this where a (to us) indeterminate pronoun refers forward. But, in Latin, the pronoun referring forward to *industria* agrees with that word, at least in this case. I suspect that *illud* would also be possible, though I think I'd prefer *illa*.

Explained in a more general way: when the subject is a pronoun (*illa*), and the subject complement is a noun (*industria*), I believe the subject would normally agree with the subject complement, even if the complement comes some ways *after* the subject, as here. In Germanic languages, I believe such a pronoun-subject is less likely to agree forward with a complement that it hasn't 'seen' yet, and we would be more likely to use an indeterminate (neuter) pronoun for the subject instead (*that*).

The text continues like this:

> Nam illa tumultu gaudens non est industria sed exagitatae mentis concursatio, et **haec** non est quies quae motum omnem molestiam iudicat, sed dissolutio et languor.

"... and **that** which judges all movement to be a nuisance is not quiet."

Here the pronoun is *haec*, agreeing with *quies*. The relative clause *quae...* agrees in turn with *haec* (whence also with *quies*).

Answer (score 6):

It refers back to the basic idea of being always restless, as expressed by *eos qui semper inquieti sunt* in the previous sentence. So the basic clause in English is 'That isn't industry.' Although we might expect the pronoun to be neuter, *illud*, in Latin, a demonstrative is very often assimilated to the gender (and number) of any predicate noun.

The rule as given in Gildersleeve & Lodge, *Latin grammar* (§211, remark 5) is:

> The demonstrative pronoun is commonly attracted into the gender of the predicate...

The following examples are cited:

> at negat **Epicurus** – **hoc** enim vestrum **lumen** est – quemquam, qui honeste non vivat, iucunde posse vivere. (Cicero, *De finibus* 2.22.70)
>
> 'But **Epicurus** – for **he** is your **light** - denies that anyone who doesn't live honorably can live pleasantly.'

Here, although the *hoc* refers back to the masculine singular noun Epicurus, so it seems as though it should really be masculine too (as in the English translation), it's neuter in Latin through assimilation or attraction to the neuter singular predicate noun *lumen*.

> nam **quod** Cleomedon modo tamquam mediam et tutissimam uobis viam consilii, ut quiesceretis abstineretisque armis, ostendebat, **ea** non media sed nulla **via** est. (Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 33.21.33)
>
> 'As for **what** Cleomedon was just now pointing out as the middle and safest course of a plan for you – namely, that you sit tight and refrain from arms – **that** isn't a middle **course** but no course at all.

Here, *ea* refers back to *quod* (which encapsulates the whole substance of Cleomedon's suggestion) but is feminine singular through attraction to *via*.

The same thing happens with *haec* in the continuation of this sentence: *et **haec*** [referring to *eos qui semper quiescunt* in the previous sentence] *non est **quies** quae motum omnem molestiam iudicat, sed dissolutio et languor*.

Relative pronouns often work the same way.

Comment: +1 for mentioning mentioning a source with examples.